# Multiple download sites for verification

Tags: security, tails

I want to download Tails and verify by comparing multiple downloads from different sites. Can anyone point me to a list of these sites please? If I go to tor project.org there is just one download button. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are either to download Tails via:

- bit-torrent;
- HTTPS from a mirror.

However, [the way that the *official* Tails mirrors work](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/how/mirror/#index5h2) is to actually act as virtual hosts with the main site pointing to them, meaning there *is* only one button, rather than a list of places from which you can download.

I'm assuming the reason for this is to prevent Bad People setting up their own private mirrors and serving compromised versions of Tails to users who don't know to download it from the official site, and therefore are ignorant to the official advice about authenticating the ISO...

...Therefore, if you're worried about the authenticity of anything you download from the official site, see if the details on [verifying the ISO](https://tails.boum.org/download/index.en.html#verify), and the more detailed page on [trusting the signing key](https://tails.boum.org/doc/get/trusting_tails_signing_key/index.en.html), set you mind at rest.

Whether or not you can trust this advice has been [discussed in the past](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7596/can-tails-confidence-suggestions-be-trusted).

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time to answer my question. I'll probably go for a BitTorrent download.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [bittorrent download](https://tails.boum.org/download/index.en.html) - it will be verified by alot of people.